# UISlider code not overriding IB defaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uislider

[heightSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(updateHeightLabel:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];I have `heightSlider` declared in the `.h` file as follows :
`@property (retain, nonatomic) UISlider *heightSlider;` and it is `@synthesize heightSlider;`
in the `.m` file.

In `IB`, I have it hooked up to the `updateHeightLabel` on `valueChanged`. I also have the default `maximumValue` and `minimumValue` set to `36.0` and `84.0` in `IB`.

The default value of `unitType` is `0`. So the `heightSlider.maximumValue` should be set accordingly and thus  `NSLog` the change from `91.0` to `213.0` but it does not. It `NSLogs` the change from the `IB` default values.

Also `[heightSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(updateHeightLabel:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` does not seem to be working either, and is only calling the function due to the connection in `IB`.

Is there something fundamental that I am doing incorrectly?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      heightSlider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
      heightSlider.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
      heightSlider.continuous = YES;
      [heightSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(updateHeightLabel:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; 

      if (unitType == 0) {
            heightSlider.maximumValue = 91.0;
            heightSlider.minimumValue = 213.0;      
}

      else if (unitType ==1 ) {

            heightSlider.maximumValue = 36.0;
            heightSlider.minimumValue = 84.0;
}

}


-(IBAction) updateHeightLabel:(id)sender {

   NSLog(@"Sender Value : %f", sender.value");

}
```

Comment: Do you have a method called updateHeightLabel?

Comment: thanks @geminiCoder, that is just a typo here. Don't have it in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've created the slider in IB, and hooked it up to your heightSlider property, then you shouldn't be doing an alloc/init to create a new one.  You're effectively creating an invisible slider (because you don't add it as a subview), and changing its properties.

Comment out the alloc/init line of code...

Comment: Thanks @CSmith, I don't normally do that. I had put it in because when I omit it the value does not update. The `NSLog` stays fixed on `91.0` and the `heightSlider` will not slide anymore, once I get rid of it. I have tried using `[heightSlider setValue:(float)sender.value];` in the `updateHeightLabel` method to set the value. Any ideas?

Comment: You're maximum value should be greater than your minimum value, it looks like you've got your max/min backwards.

Comment: Perfect. I have been looking at that for too long. Thank you very much!